# Why no other operations on file can be performed before setvbuf?

Tags: c

The documentation for glibc setvbuf (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3p.html) states:

> The setvbuf() function may be used after the stream pointed to by
>   stream is associated with an open file but before any other operation
>   (other than an unsuccessful call to setvbuf()) is performed on the
>   stream.

What is the point of having this restriction? (`but before any other operation...`)

Why it it not possible to first write to the file and then call `setvbuf()` for example?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking at the code for an implementation that does not match the documentation you are looking at. You should tell us about where you found that code, and where you found the documentation.

Comment: The citation does not say there **cannot** be operations performed. It just says there may no operations be performed. Looking at a particular implementation is useless and much the same as asking why `1 + 1 = 2` in mathematics for natural numbers.

Comment: @nos I edited the question and removed the code snippet completely. As I understand this is documentation for latest glibc.

Comment: @Olaf I changed the question an provided slightly different citation, as I understand from the latest version of libc. Please correct me if I am wrong. If so it states "but before any other operation (other than an unsuccessful call to setvbuf())". In my view it clearly states that you cannot do anything before setvbuf call.

Comment: @Alexander Ponomarev: Because it is _easier_ not bother handling the buffer transfer cases and doing so would seldom be useful. Consider how you would implement a late buffer swap yourself to see the implications to see why. For instance consider an early `getchar` buffering up 32k of data and having 32k-1 bytes left in the input buffer when a `setvbuf` call asks to swap in a smaller 16k buffer in its place.

Comment: @AlexanderPonomarev: You missed the point completely! The last sentence of my comment should make it clear if you just think about it (do some research what `1 + 1` **is**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this restriction was taken literally from Unix OS. Referring to Rationale for ANSI C:

> #### 4.9.5.6 The `setvbuf` function
>
> `setvbuf` has been adopted from UNIX System V, both to control the
> nature of stream buffering and to specify the size of I/O buffers.

A particular implementation may provide useful mechanics for UB in form of  non-portable extension. It is easier for output streams, which may be just flushed, but it gets less trivial for input streams.

Without crystal ball, I guess that it is easier to reopen the file and set the buffer, rather that think of every edge case involved in rebuffering.